# HornetQ: hooking up a topic to a queue

Tags: jms, message-queue, hornetq

I have a use case that to hook up the topic to many queues. We have some events in our system that we want to allow different users to subscribe to. We are treating that the 'events' as 'topics' and the user subscriptions as 'queue'. Each user will have a personal queue and it depending on their subscription; we will route it to their queue. Can you share some pointers as to how this can be set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on Diverts on the hornetq documentation.

Or you could just use simple Topics. Also look at topic hierarchy on the hornetq documentation.

Or maybe you could achieve what you need with simple topic subscriptions and filters? (what will be probably more portable).

Comment: Only thing that I liked with queues is the fact that even if the consumer is offline, it will get the MSG when it comes back online.

Comment: That's the core business of a message system. Topics will do the same.

Comment: I wasn't able to see the same behavior for topics (in hornetQ). I subscribed to a topic.. killed the client.. sent some messages on that topic.. brought the client online and no messages were delivered. With a queue however; as soon as the client came back online.. it got all msgs that were sent on queue

Comment: you have to use durable subscription. maybe that's what you're missing